# What is best practice for link exchange for website with multiple domains and censorship problem?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, backlinks

I have a website named something like `example.com`, but it has been filtered (blocked) in my country. So I created a new domain named something like `example2.com` and a redirect on my original `example.com` site to this new domain. This makes my new domain appear in search engine results.

I'm setting up Link Exchange for my website. What is best practice? Should I link exchange with first domain name (`example.com` that redirect to the new domain name), use the new domain, or should I link exchange with new domain (`example2.com`)?

Note: My website is filtered in my country but Google can see it.

Comment: Feeling grateful that I don't have to deal with this where I am.  Good luck @mmtemporary

Answer (score 1):

Have the link point to the new domain since that is the actual domain users and search engines will be seeing. Plus since 301 redirects cause some link value to be lost you're better of avoiding the redirect for those links and getting full value from the links.

FYI, link exchanges seem to be considered low quality and/or manipulating the search engines algorithm and *may* cause your site to be flagged as low quality as a result. I'd be careful with how many of these you do and with whom you do them with. If your doing a lot of them with low quality sites this may be more harmful than beneficial.

Comment: Please consider i must create new domain like example3.com after few month, and i must redirect to new domain... and after few month i must create example4.com. What is best practice in this condition?

Comment: There is no best practice. Search engines only follow redirects for so many hops. Eventually they give up so links to the older domains will eventually be worthless from an SEO point of view.